# Debug only Server Code in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Irritatingly, MVC does not [map JavaScript breakpoints to source files](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/652428/mvc-3-mvc-2-debug-ignores-javascript-breakpoints).  This leaves a few non-optimal options:

- Hit Ctrl-F5 and use IE's debugger.  **Downside**: Can't debug server-side at the same time.
- Insert `debugger;` statements.  **Downside**: Need to edit source code, can't add breakpoints after launch.
- Change `Web` settings to `Don't open a page.`.  Launch IE separately and browse to the URL.  **Downside**: Extra step to launch IE; Need to bookmark URL for each project.

Is it possible to configure VS 2010 to launch IE, but not in DEBUG mode, when F5 is pressed so that IE's own script debugger can function?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that views are dynamically recompiled once edits are saved.  Using that approach, I add `debugger;` statements to JavaScript in views that I wish to debug in IE.

Not quite as slick as if breakpoints were mapped to source files, but works quite well.